# После запуска JAR-файла в консоли Windows "команды" на русском отображаются верно, но не исполняются

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd

Всех приветствую!
Есть простая консольная программа, которая должна корректно обрабатывать вводимые с клавиатуры русские слова (напр., "да" или "нет") и печатать там же соответствующие сообщения на русском языке.

В IntelliJ IDEA программа работает: отображает русские буквы правильно и корректно исполняет "команды". Но если сгенерировать (использую Maven в проекте) JAR-файл и запустить его в консоли Windows 10 Pro (21H2) - `java -jar file.jar` , то русские буквы - как выводимые программой, так и вводимые с клавиатуры - отображаются нормально (без кракозябр), но те же "да" или "нет", введенные с клавиатуры, программа воспринимает как ошибочный ввод. То есть вводимые символы обрабатываются некорректно.

Переконвертация в IntelliJ (через *File - Settings - Editor - File Encodings*) c ***UTF-8*** на ***Windows-1251*** и обратно не помогает. Если при изменении кодировки (там же) выбрать *Reload* вместо *Convert*, то в коде русские слова превращаются в кракозябры.
Вот код:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Введите 'да' или 'нет':");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("да".equals(input) || "нет".equals(input)) {
                System.out.println("Вы ввели '" + input + "'");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Ошибка ввода!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажи git репозиторий с этим проектом, если есть.

Comment: Я не понял где проблема,  в IDEA или в командной строке  windows во  втором  случае   попробуйте использовать  chcp 1251 (  тка я команда вызывается в  команндной строке)

Comment: **Vladimir Glinskikh**, 
 Такого нет.

Comment: **Труфальдино**,
 я тоже не понимаю. В консоли Windows менял chcp с 866 на 1251 и обратно - не помогает.

Comment: А что, с подобным никто не сталкивался?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Vladimir Glinskikh
Программа работает с файлом русского словаря и вводом-выводом русских слов. Если вы уверены, что с консолью Windows ничего не получится, так и скажите. Вопросы типа "кто так делает?" не по существу.

Comment: Всего лишь для выделения инпута. Проблемы это не касается.

Comment: @Arslan7791 Не поленился блин и зафигачил джарник, запустил в терминале, все работает. Русские буквы и печатает и выводит корректно, как в терминале, так и в IDEA. Запускал в Linux.

Comment: Vladimir Glinskikh
Я уже писал, что тоже не ленился, и в Windows консоль у меня тоже и печатает, и выводит русские буквы, но ОБРАБАТЫВАЕТ ВВЕДЕННЫЕ РУССКИЕ СЛОВА НЕКОРРЕКТНО, т.е. введенные слова "да"/"нет" воспринимает как "Ошибка ввода!".. Если у вас обрабатывает правильно, значит, у меня с ОС что-то не то(?).. А что именно?

Comment: Vladimir Glinskikh
В моих сообщениях два раза упоминалась Windows и ни разу - Linux. Если непонятно, Linux мне не интересен. Конструктива с вашей стороны никакого ("кто работает в консоли с русскими буквами?.. еще и в Windows", "зачем одинарные кавычки?", "в Linux все работает"). Я уже и без вас понял, что проблема в Windows, ветку можно закрывать/удалять.